# External HDD Not Being Recognized

Tags: hard-drive

I have two identical bus-powered USB3 1TB hard drives (Buffalo MiniStation).

On my desktop computer, both work just fine.

On my new Win 8.1 laptop (Dell XPS 13 9343), only one works. The other one does not even show up in Disk Management (I can feel the drive spinning while plugged in, but the connection LED does not come on). Using the other USB port doesn't make a difference. Having the laptop plugged in to the AC charger does not make a difference. I have tried it on two different builds of the OS (on Dell's preinstalled package and a clean OS install onto a new SSD), and in both cases, the same issue appears.

On my OTHER laptop computer, both work just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the same USB 3.0 cable to test the external hard drives?

Comment: Just to confirm I have the right product.  These devices have an `Integrated Wrap-Around USB Cable` and have no external power supply correct?  If that's the case then despite it working on your desktop computer you have indeed encountered a failure likely with the cable itself.  I am going to guess this new laptop only has 3.0 ports and your desktop has 2.0 ports.

Comment: Yes, there is an integrated cable. All ports in question on all machines are USB3, and both drives operate without issue in USB3 mode (on all machines that recognize them). I am confused!

Comment: Have you tried using an externally powered USB hub? I'm going to guess that your laptopisn't providing enough juice to run both HDDs simultaneously. Using a powered hub with both devices may prove the disks and cables are fine and power is the problem. If it still doesn't work then you've ruled power requirements out.